# Facebook API .NET post photo to album with custom privacy

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a FB **album with custom privacy setting visible for specified people**. When I try to post an image to this album using facebook api for .NET, the image is not posted and has to be approved manually by me. **How to approve it automatically?**

P.s. I authorize with scope: email, publish_stream, publish_actions, read_stream, user_photos.
My app in facebook in login permissions have: email, public_profile, user_friends. (cannot add more because it reqiures a platform to be added).

P.p.s. When I add the image to an album with private or friends or public privacy level everything works fine and post is approved automatically